# Is @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault applies to method return values too?

Tags: java, annotations, jsr305

The [documentation for `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault`](http://jsr-305.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/javax/annotation/ParametersAreNonnullByDefault.html) says, that:

> This annotation can be applied to a package, class or method to indicate that **the method parameters** in that element are nonnull by default unless ...

I don't consider a method's return type/value to be it's parameter. It is only part of its signature, so this is kind of ambiguous for me.

The [Java tutorial for methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) seems to think like me.

---

As [Joachim Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer) pointed out for me in the comments section of his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658353/is-parametersarenonnullbydefault-applies-to-method-return-values-too/7658375#7658375), the name `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault` (**parameters**) should've clearly indicated for me that this annotation doesn't apply to methods' return types/values. I was blind! :) Thanks Joachim!

In light of this I can only says that an `@EverythingIsNonnullByDefault` should exist somwhere. :)

Comment: So what's your reason to think that this annotation _would_ apply to return values?

Comment: I don't have a reason for why it would do this, instead I would like it to be doing this. (See my comment for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658353/is-parametersarenonnullbydefault-applies-to-method-return-values-too/7658375#7658375).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a reason why `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault` should apply to return values.

Comment: My reason it that `@Nonnull` can be applied to method return values too. At least the [documentation for FindBugs' `@NonNull` annotation](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/annotations.html) (which is almost, if not the same thing as `@Nonnull`) says just that.

Comment: @Psycho_Dad: you specify the nullity of a return type, yes. But that doesn't mean that **this** default annotation influences it if you don't set one.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand you clearly. My question was if the annotation at hand applies to methods' return values too **if I set it**. I couldn't care less what it does if I don't set it. :)

Comment: By "don't set one" I meant "don't specify `@Nonnull@` or `@Nullable` on the return type explicitly".

Comment: Yeah OK, but still I want to know that if I set `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault` on a class would that implicitly apply a `@Nonnull` annotation on methods' return types or not. Because in my read applying it so implicitly applies `@Nonnull` on method parameters.

Comment: @Psycho_Dad: **why should it**? A return value is *not a parameter*. The documentation (and name!) of `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault` clearly states that it applies to *parameters*.

Comment: OK, I got it at last! :D I didn't really pay attention to the annotation's name. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

No, `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault` applies only to a method's *parameters*--the values it accepts from the caller (between the parentheses). The method is still free to return a `null` value.

Here's a class that combines all three places where you can apply `@Nonnull`, though in our code I still use three separate annotations, one of which is supplied by JSR-305.

```
package com.sample;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

import javax.annotation.meta.TypeQualifierDefault;

/**
 * This annotation can be applied to a package, class or method to indicate that all
 * class fields and method parameters and return values in that element are nonnull 
 * by default unless overridden.
 */
@Documented
@Nonnull
@TypeQualifierDefault({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EverythingIsNonnullByDefault {
}
```